# Retrieve from an API and remove Strings after white space

Tags: swift, string, api, swiftui, whitespace

**Summarize the problem** 
I've build an App and retrieving elements from an external API (Breaking Bad) and I was getting struggles of a simple String formatting. My scope is to remove after the white space the other strings.

**What I've tried** 
I tried to follow guides that tries to recognize my whitespace element from a string called : "actor.name" but I don't know how to say "now that you recognized the white space, remove me all the string after this one".
I used this parameter `actor.name..filter({!$0.isWhitespace}`
but it only recognize the white space and remove it in some way. Then I tried this : `actor.components(separatedBy: .whitespaces).joined(separator: " ")` but I think that I'm out of track.

**Show some code** 
It's not about showing a lot of my code.. I've just got this situation (I intentionally deleted useless piece of code) :

```
Text(actor.name.components(separatedBy: .whitespaces).joined(separator: " "))
            .bold()
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .padding(.horizontal)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this example code to `...remove Strings after white space`. The code first removes any leading, trailing whitespaces, then
split the string into components, and pick the first component `[0]`.

```
let txt = actor.name.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).components(separatedBy: .whitespaces)
Text(txt.count > 0 ? txt[0] : "")
        .bold()
        .foregroundColor(.red)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        .padding(.horizontal)
```

Comment: Hey dude, thanks. It works perfectly! It was just a matter of dividing the text in different indices, just like a kind of array. Thank you so much again.